# Handling null values in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In my Script Componet task  in SSIS
i am getting null value encountered error for a column.my database allows this column to be null but ssis doen not

Comment: What does your script component do? either way, an if-else / try-catch can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column is an input in the script component you have to use `_IsNull` property to check it and if it is an output you have to use the same property to assign a `null` value to it.

**i.e.**

Assume `inColumn` (input) , `OutColumn` (Output), (i used vb.net)

```
If Not Row.inColumn_IsNull Then ' check if value is not null
    ' Do something
    '...
    Row.OutColumn = value
Else
    Row.OutColumn_IsNull = True 'Assign a null value to the output
End If
```